# Ubuntu 18.04 How to merge & unmerge apps in dash

Tags: gnome-shell, appmenu

I am Using Ubuntu 18.04.

When I click "Show Applications" icon, I see "Frequent" & "All".

When I click "All", I can see some apps icons individually and some merged into "Utilities".

[image]

How can I control merging and unmerging and also create new group and putting some apps in this group & removing. Is there a way?